# C#: How to add indentation to the root element when writing an object to XML

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I need to serialize an object to an XML file, but have some formatting restrictions:

1. No namespace data.
2. No encoding tag in the first line.
3. Root element must be indented.

The following code I wrote takes care of restrictions 1 and 2:

```
public void WriteToXml(TextWriter writer)
{
    XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    ns.Add("", "");
    using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(writer, new XmlWriterSettings { OmitXmlDeclaration = true, Indent = true, IndentChars = "\t"  }))
    {
        new XmlSerializer(typeof(CalledUnit)).Serialize(xmlWriter, this, ns);
    }
}
```

and gets me the following result:

```
<CalledUnit>
    <Caller>some info</Caller>
    <CallerId>1001</CallerId>
    <Called>some more info</Called>
    <CalledId>31</CalledId>
</CalledUnit>
```

but I want the following result (note the indentation):

```
    <CalledUnit>
        <Caller>some info</Caller>
        <CallerId>1001</CallerId>
        <Called>some more info</Called>
        <CalledId>31</CalledId>
    </CalledUnit>
```

Any ideas how to tackle this problem?

Comment: ...why does that matter? Any xml parser won't care

Comment: @Jonesy, you are of course correct. The requirements are not from the parser.

Answer (score 1):

If the file ain't big you can serialize into a memory stream and then read from the stream line by line and write it into a file while prefixing with a needed space indentation. Comment if you need a code sample.

Comment: The file is big and complex, the example here is just a small cut out. But your suggestion is valid and will be used if there is no other simpler way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, this is not really an XML issue - XML doesn't really care about such whitespace issues.

However, you **could** achieve this by doing the formatting yourself.  In your `WriteToXml` method, instead of writing directly to your `TextWriter`, write to a `StringBuilder`, then run a regex on your string replacing `\r\n` with `\r\n` + the number of spaces you want to pad it by.   Alternatively, you could read your stream with something like a `StringReader.ReadLine()` and write the output of that (prepended by your spaces) to your `TextWriter`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no obvious way to do this using the .Net XML classes. (For instance, [`XmlTextWriter.Indent()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlTextWriter.cs,8b35c6ee1e58cb2d,references) isn't virtual, as shown by the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlTextWriter.cs,8b35c6ee1e58cb2d,references).)  You may need to stream the XML into intermediate representation then patch it.  However, instead of using a regex to do the patching (which can cause problems with [CDATA nodes](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp)) you could use Mark Fussell's `WriteShallowNode` from [Combining the XmlReader and XmlWriter classes for simple streaming transformations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mfussell/archive/2005/02/12/371546.aspx) to do the patching:

```
    public void WriteToXml(TextWriter writer)
    {
        var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", "");
        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings { OmitXmlDeclaration = true, Indent = true, IndentChars = "\t" };

        string xml;
        using (var tempWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(tempWriter, settings))
                new XmlSerializer(this.GetType()).Serialize(xmlWriter, this, ns);
            xml = tempWriter.ToString();
        }

        using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(reader))
        {
            XmlNodeType? prevType = null;
            using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(writer, settings))
            {
                while (xmlReader.Read())
                {
                    if ((xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element || xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement)
                         && (prevType == null || prevType == XmlNodeType.Whitespace))
                    {
                        xmlWriter.WriteWhitespace(settings.IndentChars); // Add one more indentation
                    }
                    xmlWriter.WriteShallowNode(xmlReader);
                    prevType = xmlReader.NodeType;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And then, adapting Mark Fussell's code to an extension method:

```
public static class XmlWriterExtensions
{
    public static void WriteShallowNode(this XmlWriter writer, XmlReader reader)
    {
        // adapted from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mfussell/archive/2005/02/12/371546.aspx
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("reader");

        if (writer == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("writer");

        switch (reader.NodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Prefix, reader.LocalName, reader.NamespaceURI);
                writer.WriteAttributes(reader, true);
                if (reader.IsEmptyElement)
                {
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                }
                break;

            case XmlNodeType.Text:
                writer.WriteString(reader.Value);
                break;

            case XmlNodeType.Whitespace:
            case XmlNodeType.SignificantWhitespace:
                writer.WriteWhitespace(reader.Value);
                break;

            case XmlNodeType.CDATA:
                writer.WriteCData(reader.Value);
                break;

            case XmlNodeType.EntityReference:
                writer.WriteEntityRef(reader.Name);
                break;

            case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
            case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
                writer.WriteProcessingInstruction(reader.Name, reader.Value);
                break;

            case XmlNodeType.DocumentType:
                writer.WriteDocType(reader.Name, reader.GetAttribute("PUBLIC"), reader.GetAttribute("SYSTEM"), reader.Value);
                break;

            case XmlNodeType.Comment:
                writer.WriteComment(reader.Value);
                break;

            case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                writer.WriteFullEndElement();
                break;

            default:
                Debug.WriteLine("unknown NodeType " + reader.NodeType);
                break;

        }
    }
}
```